# TypeError and InvalidIndexError - Pandas/ Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm having problems with this pandas code, apparently it's related to index , but I haven't been able to solve it yet. When I removed the columns = cols I managed to run it but it was blank, can anyone help me?

`

```
def SimulaCopa(dados):
    cols = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', 'Oitavas', 'Quartas', 'Semis', 'Final', 'Campeão']
    n = dados.shape[0]
    m = len(cols)
    aux = np.array(np.zeros(n*m).reshape(n, m))
    info = pd.DataFrame(aux,columns=cols,index= dados.index)
    info = info.astype(int)
      
    top16 = []  
    for i in list('ABCDEFGH'):
        a = JogosGrupo(dados, i)[0] 
        top16 += a.index[:2].tolist()
        anomes = a.index.to_list() 
        info.at[anomes[0], '1st'] = 1
        info.at[anomes[1], '2nd'] = 1
        info.at[anomes[2], '3rd'] = 1
        info.at[anomes[3], '4th'] = 1
    

    qf1 = JogoMataMata(top16[0], top16[3])   #A1 x B2
    qf2 = JogoMataMata(top16[2], top16[1])   #B1 x A2
    qf3 = JogoMataMata(top16[4], top16[7])   #C1 x D2 
    qf4 = JogoMataMata(top16[6], top16[5])   #D1 x C2
    qf5 = JogoMataMata(top16[8], top16[11])  #E1 x F2
    qf6 = JogoMataMata(top16[10], top16[9])  #F1 x E2
    qf7 = JogoMataMata(top16[12], top16[15]) #G1 x H2
    qf8 = JogoMataMata(top16[14], top16[13]) #H1 x G2

    top8 = [qf1, qf2, qf3, qf4, qf5, qf6, qf7, qf8]
    

    sf1 = JogoMataMata(qf1, qf3)
    sf2 = JogoMataMata(qf2, qf4) 
    sf3 = JogoMataMata(qf5, qf7) 
    sf4 = JogoMataMata(qf6, qf8) 

    top4 = [sf1, sf2, sf3, sf4]

    f1 = JogoMataMata(sf1, sf3) 
    f2 = JogoMataMata(sf2, sf4) 
    top2 = [f1, f2]

    top1 = JogoMataMata(f1, f2)

    info.at[top16, 'Oitavas'] = 1
    info.at[top8, 'Quartas'] = 1
    info.at[top4, 'Semis'] = 1
    info.at[top2, 'Final'] = 1
    info.at[top1, 'Campeão'] = 1
   

    return info
```

`

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpTBH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM15u.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMBVJ.jpg)

I removed columns=cols , I used the prints in the steps to try to identify an error and it didn't work.

Message error complete:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3800, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3799 try:
-> 3800     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3801 except KeyError as err:

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:144, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '['Holanda', 'Senegal', 'Inglaterra', 'Irã', 'Argentina', 'Arábia Saudita', 'França', 'Tunísia', 'Costa Rica', 'Alemanha', 'Bélgica', 'Marrocos', 'Suíça', 'Brasil', 'Portugal', 'Uruguai']' is an invalid key

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [216], line 1
----> 1 SimulaCopa(selecoes)

Cell In [214], line 45, in SimulaCopa(dados)
     41 top2 = [f1, f2]
     43 top1 = JogoMataMata(f1, f2)
---> 45 info.at[top16, 'Oitavas'] = 1
     46 info.at[top8, 'Quartas'] = 1
     47 info.at[top4, 'Semis'] = 1

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:2438, in _AtIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   2435     self.obj.loc[key] = value
   2436     return
-> 2438 return super().__setitem__(key, value)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:2393, in _ScalarAccessIndexer.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   2390 if len(key) != self.ndim:
   2391     raise ValueError("Not enough indexers for scalar access (setting)!")
-> 2393 self.obj._set_value(*key, value=value, takeable=self._takeable)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4209, in DataFrame._set_value(self, index, col, value, takeable)
   4207 else:
   4208     icol = self.columns.get_loc(col)
-> 4209     iindex = self.index.get_loc(index)
   4210 self._mgr.column_setitem(icol, iindex, value)
   4211 self._clear_item_cache()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3807, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802         raise KeyError(key) from err
   3803     except TypeError:
   3804         # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3805         #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3806         #  the TypeError.
-> 3807         self._check_indexing_error(key)
   3808         raise
   3810 # GH#42269

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:5963, in Index._check_indexing_error(self, key)
   5959 def _check_indexing_error(self, key):
   5960     if not is_scalar(key):
   5961         # if key is not a scalar, directly raise an error (the code below
   5962         # would convert to numpy arrays and raise later any way) - GH29926
-> 5963         raise InvalidIndexError(key)

InvalidIndexError: ['Holanda', 'Senegal', 'Inglaterra', 'Irã', 'Argentina', 'Arábia Saudita', 'França', 'Tunísia', 'Costa Rica', 'Alemanha', 'Bélgica', 'Marrocos', 'Suíça', 'Brasil', 'Portugal', 'Uruguai']
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What's the index of this dataframe?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/gitflai/MinicursoFLAIDataScienceNaCopa/blob/main/Minicurso_FLAI_Data_Science_na_Copa_do_Mundo_Qatar_2022.ipynb here o link of the code complete